# get viewControlelr appear event

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image: images]

When I touched the indication input, and click learn more, this will show from current viewController, however, when i touched the button "完成" which means done, the viewconteoller never go to the method as viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, my viewController is landscape and this is potrait,so this cause the problem, I need go get the event when this page dismissed to fix the direction, anyone had good ideas to resolve this? Thanks

Comment: None code, I explained very careful, this is the system action! When you first use the voice input, there will be three options for you to choose, the first is open and agree, second is more information, when you click the second one this page will show

Answer (score -1):

I resoled it with print all notifications, UIWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification can resolve my problem as this system page will use a new window to be keywindow, when it dismissed, the window of my viewController will be keywindow, i can use this to resolve my problem